# timeout operator in Combine times out even after an event is published

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm using the timeout operator in Combine, and my understanding was that it would timeout only if a publisher does not publish an event, but it seems to timeout even if a value is published.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/timeout(_:scheduler:options:customerror:))

> A publisher that terminates if the specified interval elapses with no events received from the upstream publisher.

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let cancellable = subject
    .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(
          receiveCompletion: { print ("completion: \($0) at \(Date())") },
          receiveValue: { print ("value: \($0) at \(Date())") }
     )

subject.send("Sending data")

/*
Prints
value: Sending data at 2021-01-06 22:41:12 +0000
completion: finished at 2021-01-06 22:41:17 +0000
*/
```

Is my understanding wrong with the operator?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of the text you quoted. It says that a publisher terminates *if the specified interval elapses with no events received*, which means, in your example, if there was no value received in the previous 5 seconds.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/timeout(_:scheduler:options:customerror:)) also provides a slightly different example that illustrates the point.

So, in other words, if you'd added this to your example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(deadline: .now() + 3) { subject.send("in 3 seconds") }
```

then you would have had the following output:

```
value: Sending data at 2021-01-06 22:41:12 +0000
value: in 3 seconds at 2021-01-06 22:41:15 +0000
completion: finished at 2021-01-06 22:41:20 +0000
```

with the completion arriving 5 seconds after the last value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This makes more sense.

Comment: What if I need to timeout only if the first element doesn't come within 5 seconds?